# Java split method on HDFS file content

Tags: java, file, hadoop, hdfs

I have a tab separated text file in HDFS. While trying to split with tab,the first column in file is not getting stored. The same code works in normal eclipse. But while running in hadoop the first column value is ignored.

Sample line from file:

```
002\tCK 00 - 01/02/2012\t100000\t0.02\t330\t3863\t3863 FOOD
```

Code snip:

```
String subvalues[] = value.split("\t");
v1= subvalues[5];
v2=subvalues[0];
v3=subvalues[1];
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

`value.split("\t")` will split by a tab character. However, there also could be spaces in this line. You may try splitting your line with space regex:

```
String subvalues[] = value.split("\\s+");
```

For your update - may be you need to escape your `\t`:  `value.split("\\t")` or `value.split("\\t|\\s+")`;

A note: usually `\t` is used as semantic delimiter for data, so you might need to parse columns after spliting by `\t`.

If this doesn't help, you could log the ascii values for your string to see what the characters are there.

Comment: Ive tried the options not working. the point is all the value other than the first are getting split properly. Dont know why it is ignoring the first field alone.

Comment: It may contain a different space-like-looking splitter. Could you just dump your ASCII/UTF8 codes to console to see what stands there?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Problem is solved. The issue was while running in mapper, where the tab separated line is getting processed. By default, first tab was used to separate key and value in mapper.Removing the property

```
job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
```

solved the problem.

Thanks